# Let $f:(0,∞) \to (0,∞)$ be a derivable function and $F(x)$ is the primitive of $f(x)$ such that $2(F(x) - f(x)) = f^{2}(x)$ for any x then...

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:(0,∞) \to (0,∞)$ be a derivable function and $F(x)$ is the primitive of $f(x)$ such that $2(F(x) - f(x)) = f^{2}(x)$ for any x then $\lim_{ x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} =1$.
$($ true or false $)?$

From the given relation I'm getting $ f'(x) = (f(x))/(f(x) +1)$
Which is greater then $1$ since $f(x) > 0$.

How can I evaluate the given limit$?$

Answer (score 1):

Just solve the differential equation and you will get $x + c = f(x) + \log f(x)$ for some constant $c$.

In detail: we have $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{f}{f+1}$, hence $\frac{f+1}{f}df = dx$. Integrate both sides.

From here it should be clear that $f(x)$ tends to $\infty$ when $x$ tends to $\infty$, and then $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + \log f(x)} \cdot \frac{x + c}{x} = 1$.

Comment: Why must $f(x)\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: If $f+\log(f)$ tends to $\infty$, then so does $f$.

Comment: Sorry I am not convinced, since $f(x)+\log f(x)$ may larger than $f(x)$ for some $x$, the upper bound goes to $\infty$ says nothing about $f(x)$, no?

Comment: To spell things out: for any $M>10$, whenever $f+\log(f) \geq M$, we have $f\geq M/2$. This is because $f < M/2$ would imply $\log(f)< \log(M/2)<M/2$ and hence $f+\log(f)<M$.

Comment: Okay, this is clever. I just made another argument complicated, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

@WhatsUp solution is correct provided that we can show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty$.

Consider $\liminf_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x):=\sup_{M>0}\inf_{x\geq M}f(x)$ and we can always find a sequence $(x_{n})$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow\infty$ and $f(x_{n})\rightarrow M$. Assuming that $M<\infty$, then from $f(x_{n})+\log f(x_{n})=x_{n}$ we quickly get a contradiction by taking $n\rightarrow\infty$. So $M=\infty$.

We infer that $\liminf_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x):=\inf_{M>0}\sup_{x\geq M}f(x)=\infty$, and hence $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty$.

I apologize for making this complicated.

Comment: Where does the term $\log(f(x)/x^2)$ come from in your “hence” statement?